# getStores().page.subscribe() VS page.subscribe() - what's the difference?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-store

I can't for the life of me understand when it is necessary to use `getStores`, and what happens if I use for example `page.subscribe()` instead of `getStores().page.subscribe()`?

Can someone provide an example of when `page.subscribe()` goes wrong, and WHAT goes wrong?

The documentation says that using `getStores()` is "safely" - I have no idea what that means.
Documentation - https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-stores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rich Harris wrote back - https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/4078#issuecomment-1048912732

> When you import `page`, you're not *actually* importing the page store. That would be impossible, because the stores aren't free-floating objects, they're scoped to your app using Svelte [context](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/context-api) (if they weren't, on the server they would be shared by everyone who makes a request).
>
> Instead, you're importing this:
>
> https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/blob/88ebc8e3033496cd842cf29fa127f5d7efc3d184/packages/kit/src/runtime/app/stores.js#L40-L47
>
> `getStores` uses context to retrieve the actual app-scoped stores:
>
> https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/blob/88ebc8e3033496cd842cf29fa127f5d7efc3d184/packages/kit/src/runtime/app/stores.js#L17-L18
>
> But you can only call `getContext` during a component's initialisation. Most of the time that's fine, because if you do something like this...
>
> ```html
> <script>
>   import { page } from '$app/stores';
> </script>
>
> <h1>{$page.url.pathname}</h1>
> ```
>
> ...Svelte is calling `page.subscribe` on your behalf (which in turn calls `getStores`, which in turn calls `getContext`) during init. But if you tried to subscribe *later* for some contrived reason...
>
> ```html
> <script>
>   import { page } from '$app/stores';
>
>   let pathname = 'untracked';
>
>   function start_subscribing() {
>     page.subscribe($page => {
>       pathname = $page.url.pathname;
>     });
>   }
> </script>
> ```
>
> ...then you'd be calling `getContext` outside component init, which would fail. If you instead use `getStores`...
>
> ```html
> <script>
>   import { getStores } from '$app/stores';
>
>   const { page } = getStores();
>
>   let pathname = 'untracked';
>
>   function start_subscribing() {
>     page.subscribe($page => {
>       pathname = $page.url.pathname;
>     });
>   }
> </script>
> ```
>
> ...you can subscribe safely.